# Data truncation error

Tags: mysql

For the following SQL I get the error:

> Data truncation occurred on a write of column 0Data was 0 bytes long and 0 bytes were transferred.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE faculty_members
(
fid        INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,   
first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
last_name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
rank       VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,        
office     CHAR(8),                        
phone      CHAR(12),            
dob        DATE NOT NULL,
salary     DECIMAL(8,2),
CONSTRAINT faculty_members_pk PRIMARY KEY(fid),         
CONSTRAINT faculty_members_ck UNIQUE(first_name,last_name,dob),    
CONSTRAINT valid_salary CHECK(salary > 0)
```

);

And these are the INSERT statements

```
INSERT INTO faculty_members(first_name,last_name,rank,office,phone,dob,salary) VALUES
('Charles', 'Xavier', 'Professor', 'HSC 641', '563-555-6020', '11/09/1942', 125000),
('Bruce', 'Banner', 'Associate Professor', 'FO1 120', '563-555-8212', '06/20/1969', 87000),
('Hank', 'McCoy', 'Professor', 'FO1 120', '563-555-8212', '06/20/1972', 95000),
('Jeane', 'Grey', 'Assistant Professor', 'ECS 547', '563-555-8239', '03/19/1975', 95000),
('Erik', 'Lehnsherr', 'Professor', 'HSC 641', '563-555-6020', '11/09/1940', 115000),
('Diana', 'Prince', 'Associate Professor', 'HSC 400', '563-555-8212', '07/28/1967', 105100),
('Logan', 'Wolverine', 'Assistant Professor', 'ECS 540', '563-555-8100', '02/27/1964', 82000),
('Ororo', 'Storm', 'Assistant Professor', 'ECS 540', '563-555-8101', '05/01/1973', 82500);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `dob` values are incorrect. MySQL's date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. Most like you're getting the default `0000-00-00` stored and the data truncation error from that.

Comment: +1 Good spot.  The full error that I see is "*Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '11/09/1942' for column 'dob' at row 1*".

Comment: Thanks Marc. @eggyal What program are you using,I am using SQuirrel SQL clent and the error I got is not detailed like the one you got.

Comment: @user1766104: I just tried on http://sqlfiddle.com.  Could be down to server version, though.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we were adding a value exceeding the column size.